# Installing Spotlight search and QuickLook in Mac (V12.1)

Tags: mac-os-x, installation

How can I install Spotlight search and QuickLook on Mac Catalina, for Mathematica version 12.1?

The most important for me is Spotlight search. Without then I can't search for text inside a .nb file, just by file name.

I believe I forgot to do this in my installation, and I don't want to reinstall It.

Some way to execute these files?
[image]

Comment: I don't think they need to be executed ... just put somewhere... let me check. on a mac here:   ~/Library/QuickLook/ and probably ~/Library/Spotlight/

Comment: or /Library/QuickLook/ and /Library/Spotlight/ BUT I have not done it so take it only as a suggestion!

Comment: I don't think they need to be installed. It should just work as it is.

Comment: At least for me, it does. I'm on macOS 10.14. I do know that several other apps provide QuickLook generators this way. It is sufficient that the app is present on your computer and that it has been used before.

Comment: @chris Tks! If you want to answer, I will accept It. You suggestion worked. I just copied the respective files to /Library/QuickLook/ and /Library/Spotlight/

Comment: Do you know if these 2 files are available somewhere? I would rather not download the whole 5GB+ archive just to install these 2 files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For QuickLook to work, the file `Wolfram Notebook.qlgenerator` needs to be copied to  `~/Library/QuickLook/` (user only) or  `/Library/QuickLook/`  (system wide).

For searching into mathematica files, the  file `Wolfram Notebook.mdimporter` needs to be copied to   `~/Library/Spotlight (user only) or`/Library/Spotlight/` (system wide).

Comment: This is not correct. These files should be left where they are. The system will pick them up. To see which QuickLook generator the system is actually using, run `qlmanage -m plugins | grep wolfram` on the command line. You should see the one inside the latest Mathematica app bundle you have installed.

Comment: as stated above I did not try myself but @Murta said it worked for him. Please delete my post once you converge with him.

Comment: Do you have a later date on 10.3 than on 12.0? Or do you have .nb files set to open with 10.3 by default?

Comment: No, I meant the date on the `.app`.

Comment: @Szabolcs The same. nb files open with 12.0

Comment: @Szabolcs, it worked for me. Neither Spotlight nor Quicklook were functional, and after copy to /Library It started to work.

Comment: @Murta Yes, it works, but it does not seem like the right solution. The system should pick these up from the latest Mathematica that you have installed. Figuring out why that doesn't happen and fixing it would be a better solution. If you install a new version of Mathematica, this older QuickLook plugin that you manually installed will now take priority.